# google Drive maxResults query

Tags: google-drive-api

When getting a list of folders (/files with a q param of: mimeType='application/vnd.google-apps.folder') the nextLink includes any maxResults param I've included, but does not include the q param, so when following the nextLink, non-folders are included in the results. If I try to add the q param to the nextLink, I get a 500 error.

How can I get the full list of folders most efficiently?
Thanks.

Comment: The inability to add the q param to the nextLink was an error on my part, so now it's working. It seems odd, though, that it's not included in the nextLink automatically, so I still hope for confirmation from the Drive folks that what I'm seeing is somehow expected (or that I've still got a misunderstanding). Thanks.

Comment: Yes, if that is the case, this is a bug. Thanks for finding the workaround, but Google should fix that.

Comment: Thanks, I have reproduced it and raised a bug. Sorry about this.

Answer (score 0):

As a bug is raised and is known it should be put as an answer to close the discussion